# Difference between debug and release

Tags: ios, objective-c, debugging, release, testflight

I have an app that runs a synchronization algorithm.

When I build and run it in debug mode (onto my iPhone 5) it all works fine.

However, when I archive it and upload it to TestFlight and then download and install to the same iPhone 5 then part of the sync doesn't work.

It doesn't crash or anything, it just doesn't run that part of the sync.

The stupid thing is that it is a line of code inside a single function that isn't running. Everything else in that function does run.

I have no idea where to start looking for this.

**EDIT**

With help from Mindaugas I've found exactly why and which bit of code is not being run.

The function is...

```
- (void)uploadData
{
    NSLog(@"pushing photos");
    for (StoredImage *storedImage in self.recordArray) {
        NSURL *url = [self urlForImageUpload:storedImage];

        if (url == nil) {
            continue;
        }

        ImageUploadOperation *uploader = [[OJFImageUploadOperation alloc] init];
        uploader.image = storedImage.image;
        uploader.url = url;
        [self.recordQueue addOperation:uploader];
    }
}
```

When I set the optimisation level to "Fastest, Smallest" it seems to mess the order of this function up.

When it enters I can see that there is a single object in the array and it enters into the loop. But then it completely skips past the first line `NSURL *url = [self urlForImageUpload:storedImage];` and goes to the end. So the upload never actually starts and it moves onto the next item.

Comment: My only thought is if the call is inside of an NSAssert method then it will turn into a no-op.

Comment: Do you application have the privileged to perform such operation ?

Comment: I'm not using NSAssert at this point. I'm just adding in some TestFlight checkpoints to find out exactly which bit isn't being run.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Release configuration by default uses different code optimization than Debug configuration, so  some code lines can be optimized and skipped

You can check/change configurations at
Target -> Build Settings -> search for Optimization Level

Comment: Thanks! I've now been able to replicate it by changing the debug optimisation-level to "Fastest-Smallest". However, I have no idea why that has an effect?

Comment: Thats what optimization is for. If compiler thinks that certain line of codes do not produce any output, and do not have any influence on other parts, it skips that.. I guess others can elaborate on this topic..

Comment: Ah, thanks again. Well I've had a deeper look and I now know (with your help) exactly which bit is not being run. I'll add to the question.

Comment: Well, I've fixed it but the fix is bizarre and no idea WHY it works no as opposed to not working before...